# Imgur image not showing on localhost

Tags: html, image, imgur

I have an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqYLI.jpg) on imgur. this image is displaying on any website except on localhost.

What might be the problem?

```
<img class="cover" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqYLI.jpg" alt="">
```

> Error: GET https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqYLI.jpg 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: 403 forbidden, means you don't have access to this source. Mostly deep/hotlinking protection. What happend if you put this code on an online environment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strangely, imgur is restricting to access the image directly from localhost. However if you access your localhost using IP address, you are able to see the image.

Example:

> http://localhost/site (not allowed)
>
> http://192.168.0.2/site (allowed)

This is not only for [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqYLI.jpg) image, but also any imgur image.

Comment: For me it was 127.0.0.1 which was not working and localhost was working. No clue why

Comment: On MacOS, Brave, it's `localhost` which is working, not `127.0.0.1`!

Answer (score 0):

They block `127.0.0.1` origin for some reason. To solve this, I added a new line to my `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1 vnbrs.localhost
```

And accessing `vnbrs.localhost:4001` (the port I was running my web server), it worked!

Please note that you have to use the [`.localhost` TLD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.localhost).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a solution to your live-server issue however:

Using Visual Studio Code editor, having tried following extentions:

- Live-server | Imgur.com not allowing the image from the src.
- preview on web server | Imgur.com is allowing the image from the src.

So if all you are interested in is figuring out how it looks and making adjustments I suggest just using preview on web server extentions.